# rearrange/decrement row and cell id after deleting dynamically added rows javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with a default row and I am adding new rows dynamically with a button click, incrementing the ID of the `tr` and the `innerText` of the first `td` with a counter. I am trying to rearrange the ID's after deleting a row. Suppose I have 5 rows and I delete row nr 3, the 4th row should have the ID 3, and the 5th should have ID 4 etc. And also whena adding new rows it should rearrange the row ID's.

Here what I have so far. I have been trying but with no success or I dont get the desired results. Could anyone help me in the right direction?

```
<table class="table text-center table-borderless" id="rfqTable" style="font-size: 12px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Descr</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>One Time</th>
            <th>Supplier</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="1" class="tableRow">
            <td class="item">1</td>
            <td><textarea name="item[1]" rows="3" cols="90" maxlength="500"></textarea></td>
            <td><input type="number" name="amount[1]"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="oneTime[1]" value="1"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="supplier[1]" value="1"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Adding row:

```
var counter = 1;
var limit = 5;

document.getElementById("newItemBoxButton").addEventListener("click", function(){

    if (counter == limit)  
    {
        alert("Max row is 5!");
    }
    else
    {
        counter ++;

        var table = document.getElementById("rfqTable");
        var row = table.insertRow(-1);
        row.setAttribute('id', counter );

        var cell0 = row.insertCell(0);
        cell0.innerHTML = counter;
        cell0.setAttribute('id', 'item');

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell1.innerHTML = '<textarea name="item[' + counter + ']" rows="3" cols="90" maxlength="500"></textarea>';

        var cell2 = row.insertCell(2);
        cell2.innerHTML = '<input type="number" name="amount[' + counter + ']" style="width: 50px;"/>';

        var cell3 = row.insertCell(3);
        cell3.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" name="oneTime[' + counter + ']" value="1">';

        var cell4 = row.insertCell(4);
        cell4.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" name="supplier[' + counter + ']" value="1">';

        var cell5 = row.insertCell(5);
        cell5.innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="deleteRow(' + counter + ')" class="deleteItemBoxButton btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>';
    }           
});
```

Deleting row:

```
function deleteRow(rowid)  
{  

    var row     = document.getElementById(rowid);
    var table   = row.parentNode;
    while (table && table.tagName != 'TABLE')
    {
        table = table.parentNode;
        if (!table)
        {
            return; 
        }               
        table.deleteRow(row.rowIndex);
        counter--;
    }

    var table   = document.getElementById('rfqTable');
    var trRows  = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    var tdRows  = table.getElementsByTagName('td');

    for (var i = 0; i < trRows.length; i++) 
    {
        trRows[i].id = counter;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < tdRows.length; i++) 
    {
            document.getElementById("item").innerText = counter;
    }
}
```

After deleting a row, all the row id's turn into the same id, and the `td item` doesnt change at all.

Comment: What do you need those IDs for in the first place …? There’s lots of other ways to select elements.

Comment: @CBroe im using the IDs for the customers, so when a row will be deleted, it has to be rearranged for the customer. Else its just gonna continue from 1,2,5,6 etc

Comment: Ah, so the main issue would actually be to update the form field _names_ ... and not the table row ids (which don’t seem to serve much of a purpose at all - apart from selecting the row to begin with, using the id that matches the row index. So you might as well use the row index instead of the id to get the element in the first place.)

Comment: got a fix, thanks for the input @CBroe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I got a fix. I targeted the first column of every row and changed that value. For loop has to start at 1, else it will also target the first `th`. So now the IDs will be rearranged after deleting a row and the value will always start at 1.

```
var table   = document.getElementById('rfqTable');
for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) 
{
   var firstCol = table.rows[i].cells[0];
   firstCol.innerText = i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In deleteRow function, why you have added this -

```
for (var i = 0; i < trRows.length; i++) {
    trRows[i].id = counter;
}
```

You are assigning same value to all rows since your counter variable is not changing. It should be like this -

```
trRows[i].id = i + 1; // added + 1 since you want to start from 1 not 0
```

Comment: thanks for that, seems logical of course. I didnt add the + 1 tho, becuase then the first row would also increment.